# Moving luacode to Lua file, accessing glyphs by name

Tags: symbols, luatex, unicode, luaotfload

I have a package that includes (basically) the following code (provided by a contributor after asking [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123929/) on tex.stackoverflow).

```
\begin{luacode}
  documentdata = documentdata or { }
  documentdata.fontchar = function (chr)
    local chr = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), chr, false)
    print(chr)
    if chr and type(chr) == "number" then
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\char"%X]], chr))
    end
  end
\end{luacode}
\def\fontchar#1{\directlua{documentdata.fontchar "#1"}}
```

This function locates a glyph from a font by its name and prints it to the TeX document.

I am starting to convert the package to a Lua-only package and want to move that code in a separate Lua file. (Eventually the function should *not* use `tex.sprint` but return a string, and I would like to know if it's possible to pass around such glyphs through Lua, but that's a follow-up issue).

However, when I do what I thought was a correct translation I get an error:

```lua
local character = {}

function character.char_by_name(name)
    local chr = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), name, false)
    if chr and type(chr) == "number" then
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\char"%X]], chr))
    else
        tex.sprint('f') -- 'forte' character to show "not found"
    end
end

return character
```

It says `luaotfload | aux : invalid parameters to slot_of_name (16, nil)false`. Actually this sounds reasonable, given that the documentation of `aux.slot_of_name` in the `luaotfload` manual states `aux.slot_of_name(name : string)` as the function's signature. Given that documentation I'm wondering why this did even work in the first place, in the `luacode` environment.

Here is the complete MWE. I assume it can be compiled when `lilyglyphs` (or the music collection) is installed in TeX Live, because it installs the used special font with it. This is the `.tex` file, with the above Lua example saved in `character.lua`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{luaotfload,luacode}

\begin{luacode}
  documentdata = documentdata or { }
  documentdata.fontchar = function (chr)
    local chr = luaotfload.aux.slot_of_name(font.current(), chr, false)
    if chr and type(chr) == "number" then
      tex.sprint(string.format([[\char"%X]], chr))
    end
  end
\end{luacode}
\def\fontchar#1{\directlua{documentdata.fontchar "#1"}}

% Alternative implementation in Lua file
\directlua{lua_char = require('character.lua')}
\newcommand{\luafontchar}[1]{\directlua{lua_char.char_by_name(#1)}}

\font\mainfont="emmentaler-11" at 20pt

\begin{document}
    \mainfont
    \noindent
    \fontchar{clefs.C}\\
    \fontchar{clefs.G}\\
    \fontchar{flags.u7}

    \bigskip
    \luafontchar{Something}
\end{document}
```

The calls to `\fontchar` produce the expected glyphs from the Emmentaler font, while `\luafontchar` causes the mentioned error and prints the fallback glyph.

[image: Results]

Comment: You are not passing the glyph name as string. It should be `lua_char.char_by_name("#1")`

Comment: WHAT, *that* was the culprit? Oh my.

Comment: Should this question be marked invalid, because the solution/error is totally unrelated to what I was seemingly asking about?

Comment: I was desperately looking for a luaLaTeX-equivalent of the `\namedglyph` command provided by `xltxtra` for XeLaTeX. I use it to access alternative glyphs or ligatures that don't have a Unicode-codepoint attached. The first block of code in your question does exactly this. I am writing this description here so others might find it more easily. Thanks and please _don't_ delete the question!