# Is there any way to use OpenType’s “access all alternates” feature in XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, fontspec, opentype

This is inspired by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/235556/28608), where an alternate character of a font is only available via OpenType’s *access all alternates* (`aalt`) feature. My question is simply: **Is it possible to access this feature in some way or even as intended with XeLaTeX?**

Fontspec, which should be the obvious choice for this, does not mention this feature in its manual. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/208340/28608) does not do this for reasons explained in a comment.

Comment: You can try adding the feature with `RawFeature=+aalt`

Comment: However, enabling `aalt` will also use small caps.

Comment: @egreg: `RawFeature=+aalt` seems to acivate all the first alternatives from `aalt` (which probably are the respective small caps in some fonts, but not always). So it gives you access to some of the characters, but not all and not on a per-character basis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can assess glyphs by name:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
 %for comparision:
\setsansfont[RawFeature=+aalt]{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
Lessingstraße \XeTeXglyph\the\XeTeXglyphindex "germandbls.sc" \relax 

\sffamily Lessingstraße

\end{document}
```

[image]

The main problem is to find out the correct name (I used the font cache file created by lualatex).

Comment: Wonderful. By the way, you can see the glyph names in FontForge and probably any other decent font editor.